# Error opening webcam in opencv Mac OS

Tags: python, opencv

I install OpenCV 2.4.6.1 using homebrew on Mac OS Maverick. I tried connecting to webcam using this code but it returns False rval and None frame:

```
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
rval, frame = webcam.read()
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: try it cv2.VideoCapture(-1)  it may help !

Comment: passing in -1 gave me a working built-in isight camera, as did 0.  passing in 1 should give webcam from what i have heard, but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same experience.

I solved it following way.

brew install https://raw.github.com/minrk/homebrew-science/opencv-2.4.7.1/opencv.rb

Comment: The link doesn't seem working? Can you please update?

Comment: I hope this link helps you. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/commit/25b121d7f3405187e01a12ac66ce7df4207f4597 But ,now three is OpenCV version up to 2.4.8.

Comment: can you explain what the above is doing?  i already have cv2 - how does the above fix?